# HTML/CSS: show (part of) hyperlink destination as link text without repetition in source code?

Tags: html, css, markdown

I'd like to automatically have a style for using (part of) the hyperlink destination as link text without manually repeating it in the source code. Context: I'm using a Markdown file (only basic HTML and CSS) to note down many external links to academic publications. For example, a link should look and work like [journal.pbio.0020449](https://doi.org/10.1371/journal.pbio.0020449), but without having to repeat the chunk `journal.pbio.0020449` in the source code. Phrased differently, I'd like to automatically use the hyperlink destination as link text. If possible, only the last part of the displayed thereby. How could this be done?

So far, I only achieved to change the appearance of the link:

```
<style>
  a.doi {color: red;}
</style>

<a class="doi" href="https://doi.org/10.1371/journal.pbio.0020449">journal.pbio.0020449</a>
```

Comment: for markdown with only basic HTML and CSS no chance. Both HTML and Markdown are "merely" markup languages to format documents (originally scientific publications). For what you're trying to do you would at least require a scripting language such as JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the anchor element's after pseudo element to show the href value.

```html
<style>
  .doi::after {
    content: attr(href);
  }
</style>
<a class="doi" href="https://doi.org/10.1371/journal.pbio.0020449"></a>
```

However, I don't recommend it if your site is for wide publication because screen reader users will not necessarily hear the value.

Comment: Thanks! Screen readers are no issue, since it's only for internal use. Your solution works nicely, but I guess shortening/trunctating the link text to only show the part after of the last slash is not possible with pure CSS?

Comment: I don't think it is possible with pure CSS. You could show the last n characters (using a monospace font and positioning and a bit of hackery) but that's not going to be useful!

Comment: @Thanks! Since this should be quite doable with JavaScript (although I myself don't now much about it), I'm considering switching to HTML instead of Markdown ...